# Retriving data from firebase into javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make a website where user can add new product to firebase realtime database and look at all products in the database.

I managed to to add data to database like this:

```
function fun1() {
    var x = document.getElementById("input");
    firebase.database().ref("products").push({
        id: x.elements[0].value,
        product_name: x.elements[1].value,
        price: x.elements[2].value
    });

}
```

Here is my database structure: [database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKTdN.jpg)

My question is now how to get that data from firebase to javascript?

I've tried using this:

```
var dbRef = database.ref('products');
dbRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
      var childData = childSnapshot.val();
    });
});
```

But I get an error that ref is not defined. Tried also using like like in function for adding (firebase.database.ref), but another error pops up.

Also quick side question, how can I change default firebase id (that timestamp)?

I read alot of guides but none helps, not sure if Firebase updated or am I missing something?

Comment: What exactly is `database` in `database.ref(...)`?

Comment: `var database = firebase.database();` When I try to use this, I get an error that firebase.database() is not a function, and Im copying it from Firebase's official site.

Comment: `firebase` is a global variable that's created when you import the SDK.  You're actually using `firebase.database()` in your other code snippet.  What's the difference between the snippets?

Comment: When I'm using `firebase.database()` manually without `var database = firebase.database()` in first snippet, pushing function works just fine, but when i try to delcare `var database = firebase.database()`, I get an error that firebase.database() is not a function. Could i be importing the SDK wrong? I'm using `<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.7.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.7.0/firebase-database.js"></script>` in my html file.

Comment: `firebase.database()` should return exactly the same thing every time without fail if you've previously initialized successfully.

Comment: Please make sure that your question contains a single standalone piece of code that reproduces the problem, and that it includes the complete exact error message that you get from that snippet. Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).